# Intel Fortran: use of elemental intrinsic in parameterized type definition

Tags: types, fortran, derived

I am using a parameterized type `grid_f(g_size)` which has a `real` array of `dimension(max0(something_1,something_2))`. Somehow the `ifort` compiler doesnt like this, resulting in an internal error.

```
module mdl
implicit none

save

  integer, parameter ::  ng=10, dp=8

  type grid_f(g_size)
    integer, len                                      ::  g_size
      real(dp), dimension(max0(2*g_size+10, g_size))  ::  val
  end type

contains

  subroutine grid_reset(func)
  implicit none
  type(grid_f(ng))  ::  func
    func%val=0d0
  end subroutine grid_reset_orb

end module mdl
```

Compiling:

```
ifort -c check.f90
check.f90(10): error #7974: An elemental intrinsic function here must be of type integer and each argument must be an initialization expression of type integer or character.   [MAX0]
      real(dp), dimension(max0(2*g_size+10, g_size))  ::  val
--------------------------^
check.f90(17): internal error: Please visit 'http://www.intel.com/software/products/support' for assistance.
  type(grid_f(ng))  ::  func
^
[ Aborting due to internal error. ]
compilation aborted for check.f90 (code 1)
```

Using `max` or `jmax0` instead doesn't help. Any suggestions?

Edit: The topic is now on Intel site, [click](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-fortran-compiler-for-linux-and-mac-os-x/topic/798281). It seems to be a bug in ifort16 and ifort17 with compiler crash and resulting in an error in 18 and 19m, although it should be standard.

Comment: Internal errors are always bad, and in this case you should follow the advice the compiler itself gives and contact Intel support.

Comment: Which compiler version are you using, also check with the latest compiler.

Comment: I have only ifort 16.0.3 20160415 available.

Comment: Internal error is really what it says, a bug in the compiler. You can only find a workaround (by trial and error) or get a new version, if it is supposed to fix it. Intel support would tell you if that is the case or not and whether it is a known error. They are normally very active in their support forum (unlike here, at least when it comes to current official support Intel staff).

Comment: I posted the issue on the Intel forum and will update my question here, as soon as I get an sufficient answer.

Comment: Re your edit: notice Juergen says the code is still refused by ifort v 18 and 19, just with a graceful error message instead of a compiler crash.